# How can I pull data from multiple tabs in a Google Spreadsheet using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I merge multiple tabs in a Google Spreadsheet using Google App Script? A new tab is added every Monday with the name of that tab being the current date.

For example, I currently have tabs named '7/10/2023', '7/17/2023', '7/24/2023', however a new tab will be created next week named '7/21/2023'. As new tabs are created, I want to merge all the data from the Range A2:C1002 on each of these tabs into a master tab.

I am currently using this formula: =QUERY({'7/10/2023'!A3:C;'7/17/2023'!A3:C},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3", 1) however the new date needs to be added to the formula manually every Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion.  This could be added as a timed trigger to run only on Monday.  It creates the new sheet and copies last weeks data to the Master sheet.  Once the new sheet is created it won't create a new sheet or copy data until next week.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let today = new Date();
    let day = today.getDay(); // 0 - 6 Sunday to Saturday
    day = day-1;  //
    // if( day > 0 ) {  // for testing uncomment this line and comment the next line
    if( day === 0 ) { // its Monday
      let date = today.getDate()-day;
      day = new Date(today.setDate(date));
      let name = Utilities.formatDate(day,"PST","MM/dd/yyyy");
      let sheetNew = spread.getSheetByName(name);
      if( !sheetNew ) {
        sheetNew = spread.insertSheet(name,0);  // insert as first sheet
        // get last weeks data
        day = today.getDate()-7;  // last Monday
        day = new Date(today.setDate(day));
        name = Utilities.formatDate(day,"PST","MM/dd/yyyy");
        let sheetOld = spread.getSheetByName(name);
        let headers = sheetOld.getRange(1,1,1,3).getValues();
        sheetNew.getRange(1,1,1,3).setValues(headers);
        let rangeOld = sheetOld.getRange(2,1,sheetOld.getLastRow()-1,3);
        sheetNew = spread.getSheetByName("Master");
        let rangeNew = sheetNew.getRange(sheetNew.getLastRow()+1,1,rangeOld.getNumRows(),3)
        rangeOld.copyTo(rangeNew);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**References**

- [Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
- [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=en#formatDate(Date,String,String))
- [Spreadsheet.insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Integer))
- [Range.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function mergedatetabs() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  const vs = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getName().match(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/)?sh.getName():'').map(sh => {
    let ar1 = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    let ar2 = [...Array.from(new Array(ar1[0].length),(x,i) => {if(i == 0) {return sh.getName()} else {return ""}})]
    ar1.unshift(ar2);
    return ar1;
  });
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  vs.forEach((a,i) => sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, a.length,a[0].length).setValues(a));
}
```

My sample data merge into Master Tab:

| 1/1/2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |
| 2 | 3 | 16 | 15 | 21 | 18 | 7 | 4 | 21 |
| 4 | 1 | 16 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 21 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 24 | 17 | 22 | 14 | 11 | 6 | 0 | 12 |
| 17 | 16 | 15 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 7 | 21 | 7 |
| 13 | 21 | 10 | 18 | 21 | 12 | 15 | 21 | 18 |
| 0 | 14 | 16 | 12 | 2 | 15 | 16 | 21 | 15 |
| 19 | 16 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 7 | 8 |
| 24 | 9 | 14 | 17 | 24 | 5 | 2 | 21 | 11 |
| 18 | 12 | 3 | 11 | 18 | 6 | 17 | 15 | 20 |
| 7 | 4 | 23 | 12 | 16 | 10 | 9 | 2 | 8 |
| 14 | 17 | 22 | 4 | 0 | 8 | 18 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 14 | 0 | 21 | 3 | 0 | 16 | 17 | 1 |
| 9 | 15 | 22 | 12 | 3 | 15 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 11 | 0 | 10 | 16 | 3 | 8 | 1 | 16 | 9 |
| 22 | 6 | 15 | 12 | 0 | 15 | 14 | 6 | 9 |
| 11 | 9 | 8 | 1 | 6 | 14 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 23 | 24 | 9 | 17 | 7 | 12 | 9 | 6 | 20 |
| 14 | 18 | 7 | 16 | 15 | 20 | 22 | 20 | 8 |
| 1 | 15 | 6 | 4 | 22 | 9 | 9 | 5 | 0 |
| 24 | 24 | 6 | 6 | 19 | 5 | 23 | 7 | 0 |
| 13 | 19 | 1 | 4 | 15 | 7 | 14 | 1 | 4 |
| 9 | 23 | 23 | 0 | 21 | 24 | 7 | 1 | 3 |
| 17 | 15 | 14 | 14 | 19 | 22 | 8 | 11 | 7 |
| 0 | 21 | 2 | 2 | 13 | 7 | 9 | 14 | 18 |
| 13 | 3 | 20 | 9 | 0 | 24 | 2 | 11 | 10 |
| 10/15/2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 11 | 3 | 17 | 4 | 24 |
| 3 | 6 | 12 | 14 | 10 | 15 | 13 | 6 | 22 |
| 5 | 15 | 5 | 9 | 9 | 1 | 23 | 21 | 20 |
| 20 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 2 | 13 | 8 | 12 | 3 |
| 3 | 9 | 0 | 6 | 10 | 23 | 24 | 9 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 17 | 5 | 12 | 11 | 18 | 18 | 2 |
| 3 | 16 | 13 | 22 | 14 | 20 | 18 | 15 | 18 |
| 7 | 10 | 3 | 6 | 24 | 16 | 5 | 16 | 12 |
| 5 | 16 | 14 | 9 | 10 | 12 | 12 | 3 | 5 |
| 23 | 11 | 10 | 4 | 16 | 6 | 4 | 6 | 11 |
| 8 | 4 | 21 | 24 | 14 | 10 | 22 | 3 | 4 |
| 14 | 24 | 13 | 14 | 16 | 13 | 0 | 24 | 19 |
| 7 | 19 | 13 | 22 | 9 | 21 | 16 | 14 | 24 |
| 22 | 24 | 5 | 24 | 13 | 7 | 16 | 12 | 6 |
| 21 | 16 | 21 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 17 | 16 |
| 11 | 14 | 8 | 19 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 21 |
| 23 | 5 | 13 | 14 | 3 | 11 | 15 | 15 | 24 |
| 3 | 17 | 16 | 7 | 22 | 9 | 23 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 9 | 20 | 23 | 7 | 16 | 19 | 24 | 21 |
| 24 | 12 | 18 | 4 | 2 | 20 | 22 | 11 | 15 |
| 8 | 8 | 6 | 22 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 13 |
| 23 | 13 | 14 | 5 | 17 | 7 | 13 | 15 | 19 |
| 16 | 1 | 20 | 0 | 14 | 1 | 11 | 7 | 21 |
| 3 | 7 | 8 | 16 | 11 | 21 | 8 | 15 | 21 |
| 6 | 4 | 3 | 11 | 11 | 7 | 14 | 21 | 16 |
| 12/22/2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |
| 21 | 21 | 19 | 2 | 18 | 1 | 20 | 17 | 1 |
| 22 | 6 | 0 | 13 | 8 | 1 | 18 | 19 | 22 |
| 22 | 3 | 18 | 1 | 24 | 13 | 0 | 17 | 5 |
| 22 | 21 | 5 | 23 | 6 | 7 | 12 | 17 | 22 |
| 9 | 24 | 10 | 6 | 13 | 13 | 6 | 16 | 13 |
| 16 | 14 | 12 | 16 | 24 | 23 | 16 | 18 | 3 |
| 12 | 14 | 0 | 18 | 22 | 18 | 6 | 4 | 13 |
| 23 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 15 | 0 | 16 |
| 16 | 3 | 9 | 10 | 6 | 20 | 7 | 21 | 0 |
| 6 | 22 | 9 | 8 | 24 | 13 | 5 | 24 | 17 |
| 14 | 16 | 20 | 9 | 5 | 12 | 11 | 18 | 2 |
| 7 | 13 | 12 | 10 | 24 | 14 | 20 | 21 | 20 |
| 24 | 23 | 16 | 21 | 19 | 9 | 6 | 3 | 18 |
| 16 | 21 | 19 | 16 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 8 |
| 8 | 7 | 14 | 2 | 0 | 8 | 18 | 4 | 8 |
| 11 | 20 | 18 | 0 | 11 | 3 | 0 | 8 | 1 |
| 4 | 15 | 15 | 16 | 8 | 12 | 4 | 19 | 11 |
| 18 | 6 | 23 | 4 | 11 | 6 | 14 | 14 | 21 |
| 10 | 14 | 20 | 21 | 24 | 9 | 20 | 6 | 19 |
| 5 | 8 | 23 | 11 | 17 | 2 | 19 | 24 | 20 |
| 13 | 22 | 15 | 20 | 10 | 14 | 5 | 17 | 11 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 10 | 20 | 20 | 2 | 10 | 10 |
| 12 | 21 | 2 | 4 | 21 | 1 | 18 | 4 | 19 |
| 13 | 18 | 2 | 12 | 20 | 14 | 1 | 24 | 16 |
| 14 | 11 | 18 | 16 | 9 | 22 | 20 | 24 | 14 |